# Проблема с selectом из 2 таблиц

Tags: mysql

Здравствуйте, мне нужно вытащить данные из таблицы `users`, а теперь и из `user_setting` написал вот такой запрос:

```
SELECT u.*,us.use_ip FROM users AS u, user_setting AS us WHERE u.login = :login AND u.password = :password AND u.id = us.id_user
```

Вот что возвращает сервер:

```
array(20) {
  ["id"]=>
  string(3) "657"
  [0]=>
  string(3) "657"
  ["login"]=>
  string(5) "test"
  [1]=>
  string(5) "test"
  ["password"]=>
  string(32) "05f5629cf11696f786859c449e1d0ce2"
  [2]=>
  string(32) "05f5629cf11696f786859c449e1d0ce2"
  ["email"]=>
  string(16) "123@mail.ru"
  [3]=>
  string(16) "123@mail.ru"
  ["date_register"]=>
  string(10) "1379185632"
  [4]=>
  string(10) "1379185632"
  ["name"]=>
  string(0) ""
  [5]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["surname"]=>
  string(0) ""
  [6]=>
  string(0) ""
  ["age"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [7]=>
  string(1) "0"
  ["status"]=>
  string(1) "1"
  [8]=>
  string(1) "1"
  ["use_ip"]=>
  string(1) "0"
  [9]=>
  string(1) "0"
}
```

Почему id 2? логина 2? и т.д?

Comment: Используйте режим "разфетчивания", как **FETCH_ASSOC/MYSQLI_ASSOC**. Тогда у вас будет только ассоциативный массив. А так, вы разбираете в режиме **FETCH_BOTH/MYSQLI_BOTH**, в результате чего возвращется и ассоциативный массив, численный.

Comment: Я указал БД, а работаю с ней в пхп при помощи PDO

Comment: Тогда можно сделать по такой схеме:

    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);  
    while($row = $STH->fetch()) {  
        // Чаво-то делаем-с
    }
    // Или 
    $STH->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    $arrValues = $STH->fetchAll();
    // И далее работаете с $arrValues, как с обычным массивом
    // напр., с помощью foreach

Comment: не, у меня там только одну строку нужно вытащить, указал как вы сказали фетч_ассок и всё норм работает) ещё вопрос, я проверяю есть ли в бд такая строка при помощи fetchColumn(), но после неё fetch() не работает, приходиться ещё раз писать execute() а потом уже в массив совать

if ($sql->fetchColumn() > 0)

{ 

// Пользователь найден

$sql->execute();

$row = $sql->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

я хотел бы узнать на сколько это правильно?

Comment: Для таких целей есть [rowCount()][1]


$sql->execute();
if($sql->rowCount() > 0){
   // что-то в выборку попало
} else {
   // полный голяк ;)
}

   [1]:http://www.php.net/manual/ru/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Answer (score 1):

Возможно потому, что вы просто выбираете данные из двух таблиц, и это id есть в обеих таблицах?

Попробуйте

```
SELECT u.*,us.use_ip FROM users AS u
LEFT JOIN user_setting AS us 
ON u.id = us.id
WHERE u.login = :login AND u.password = :password AND u.id = us.id_user
```